# Is there a way to configure AWS Lightsail database public mode by API?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I know that I can set the public mode of the database in the AWS Lightsail console.

However, if I want to configure it using the AWS Lightsail API, I can't find a way to do so.

I already looked at Lightsail API reference, but I couldn't discover anything like that.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lightsail/2016-11-28/api-reference/Welcome.html

My goal is to do the migration with github actions. To do so, I believe I need to put it into public mode once. Then I would like to disable the public mode once the migration is done. I can do it manually but it's more smart using API.

If anyone knows, please tell me how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you are looking for is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lightsail/2016-11-28/api-reference/API_UpdateRelationalDatabase.html) although I recommend using the [AWS CLI Tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lightsail/update-relational-database.html) instead of making raw API calls.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This is just what I was looking for! You're right, it's better to use AWS CLI. I'll try that.